# python if statement on dictionary value

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement

I have created a dictionary:

```
print dict

{'a': [['1', ' 2', ' 3']], 'b': [['2', ' 3', ' 4'], ['3', ' 4', ' 2']], 'c': [['1', ' 6', ' 2']]}
```

I cant figure out how to produce an if statement val[0].

```
if val[0]dic
 print val[0]
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Please post the desired output

Comment: You question is not clear, please post the output

Comment: hi, sorry this is not clear. I'm trying to write an if statement on the first value in my dictionary. if 2 exists then print 2. Does that help?

Comment: @Dustin Dictionaries are not ordered so there is no first item, consider using a list. Can you add the output to the question?

Comment: Suggest you try creating a few `dict` objects and `print` them. You'll see that the contents come out in a different order than the way you put them in.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong data type for indexing. If you want sorted keys, [this post](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52306-to-sort-a-dictionary/) on ActiveState shows one way to sort unordered dictionary keys.

[Ordered dictionaries](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects) are stable in their ordering, but are still not indexable objects. You need to revisit what you're trying to do, and define your problem domain more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want a dictionary type if you are trying to access the elements by index.  Dictionary's are hash based lookup containers, indexed by a key. In your example:

```
>>> va['a']
[['1', ' 2', ' 3']]
```

You can test for a key presence using:

```
if 'a' in va:
    print('a is in va')
```

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict

Comment: but, I'm after the first value from the dictionary. Does that make sense?

Comment: Please test your samples in the REPL before posting them. Your if-statement is missing a required trailing colon.

Comment: This was one attempt: 

    if 2 in dic.items(0)
     print 2

Comment: @Dustin: No, that doesn't make sense. Dictionaries are unordered. OrderedDict to the rescue: http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects